# Oauth protected rest api is working without bearer token

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, oauth

The Rest endpoint is protected with `OAuth` but for some reason, I can hit `/users/user` without the token. Please let me know what is missing.

In my resource class, I have mentioned below configurations to protect the endpoint.

```java
@Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.
                anonymous().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/users/**")
                .access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe need more information, but try this:

```
@Override public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { 
   http.authorizeRequests()
   .antMatchers("/users*//**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
   .and().exceptionHandling()
   .accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler()); 
}

or original pattern "/users/**"
```